# How to Assign a value to the Model from a viewBag in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a string property in my model called **extraValue**, and in the view i got a **ViewBag** with a value, and I want to assign the Value in the viewbag to the Model property (extraValue)

I tried:

```
@{Model.extraValue = ViewBag.id}
```

and I got a **null** value in the extraValue, I'm pretty sure that ViewBag.id holds a number.

any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get the value from the ViewBag when you post it.

ViewBag is desiged to put some useful data and `accessible at rendering view only`

If you want to access then you need to preserve in your view using some Hidden Field.

```
@{Model.extraValue = ViewBag.id}
```

and

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.extraValue).
```

Now you can able to get the extraValue in the controller, since you posting back with the help of HiddenField

```
public ActionResult Save(Model model)
{
   var extra=model.extraValue;// this will bring your viewbag id assigned
}
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't make much sense. If you're able to set a value in the `ViewBag`, then you can just as easily set it directly on your the model itself, negating the need to use `ViewBag`. If your confusion is around not having a model instance until render time (by just doing `return View()`, you can actually pass a model instance into `View()`, i.e. `var model = new Something { extraValue = 1 }; return View(model);`

Comment: @ChrisPratt, thats true, he could have set the value in controller and then use it in a view. Not sure what is the purpose of reading it from ViewBag, if it simply set in controller call(load)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely setting the ViewBag value in the action method. Something like:

```
ViewBag.id = idValue;
```

You are also passing in a model to the View:

```
return View(myModel)
```

I would recommend you set the `extraValue` property in the controller, rather than in the view:

```
myModel = idValue;
return View(myModel);
```

Comment: I can't do that because the method uses a different model

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden type input by setting its 'name' attribute as Model variable to get the value to post method.

```
<input type="hidden" name="extraValue" value="@ViewBag.id"/>
```